# Java reflection - impact of setAccessible(true)

Tags: java, reflection

I'm using some annotations to dynamically set values of fields in classes. Since I want to do this regardless of whether it's public, protected, or private, I am a calling `setAccessible(true)` on the Field object every time before calling the `set()` method. My question is what kind of impact does the `setAccessible()` call have on the field itself?

More specifically, say it is a private field and this set of code calls `setAccessible(true)`. If some other place in the code was then to retrieve the same field through reflection, would the field already be accessible? Or does the `getDeclaredFields()` and `getDeclaredField()` methods return new instances of a Field object each time?

I guess another way of stating the question is if I call `setAccessible(true)`, how important is it to set it back to the original value after I'm done?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

With `setAccessible()` you change the behavior of the `AccessibleObject`, i.e. the `Field` instance, but not the actual field of the class. Here's the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible(boolean)) (excerpt):

> A value of `true` indicates that the reflected object should suppress checks for Java language access control when it is used

And a runnable example:

```java
public class FieldAccessible {
    public static class MyClass {
        private String theField;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        Field field1 = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("theField");
        field1.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println(field1.get(myClass)); // no exception
        Field field2 = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("theField");
        System.out.println(field2.get(myClass)); // IllegalAccessException
    }

}
```

Comment: @PhilipRego you need to write the import declarations yourself. I hope that you know how to do that.

Comment: Found issue. You have to throw or handle NoSuchFieldException or parent.

Comment: Yeah, this is just sample code. I mean, `throws Exception` also handles `NoSuchFieldException`, but you may want to handle it in a more elaborate way.

Comment: I am getting the Exception on the: 
Field field1 = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("theField");
so it doesn't even compile, i.e. setAccessible won't even matter?

Answer (score 45):

The `getDeclaredField` method has to return a new object each time, exactly because this object has the mutable `accessible` flag. So there is no need to reset the flag. You can find the full details in [this blog post](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=164042).

Answer (score 8):

As other posters have indicated, `setAccessible` is only applicable to that instance of your `java.lang.reflect.Field`, so setting the accessibility back to its original state is not needed.

However...

If you want your calls to `field.setAccessible(true)` to be persistent you need to use underlying methods in `java.lang.Class` and `java.lang.reflect.Field`. The public facing methods send you *copies* of the `Field` instance, so it *"forgets"* after each time you do something like `class.getField(name)`

```
import java.lang.reflect.*;
import sun.reflect.FieldAccessor;

public class Reflect {
    private static Method privateGetDeclaredFields;
    private static Method getFieldAccessor;

    public static Field[] fields(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {
        return (Field[]) privateGetDeclaredFields.invoke(clazz, false);
    }

    public static <T> T get(Object instance, Field field) throws Exception {
        return ((FieldAccessor) getFieldAccessor.invoke(field, instance)).get(instance);
    }

    public static void set(Object instance, Field field, Object value) throws Exception {
        ((FieldAccessor) getFieldAccessor.invoke(field, instance)).set(instance, value);
    }

    static {
        try {
            // These are used to access the direct Field instances instead of the copies you normally get through #getDeclaredFields.
            privateGetDeclaredFields = Class.class.getDeclaredMethod("privateGetDeclaredFields", boolean.class);
            privateGetDeclaredFields.setAccessible(true);
            getFieldAccessor = Field.class.getDeclaredMethod("getFieldAccessor", Object.class);
            getFieldAccessor.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Should only occur if the internals change.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: This implementation is for Java 8, future versions change the backend which breaks this. The same concept still applies though should you really wish to continue this strategy.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class PrivateVariableAcc {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PrivateVarTest myClass = new PrivateVarTest();
        Field field1 = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
        field1.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("This is access the private field-"
            + field1.get(myClass));
        Method mm = myClass.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getA");
        mm.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("This is calling the private method-"
            + mm.invoke(myClass, null));
    }

}
```