# Invoke a method of a private object defined in a class (Java reflection)

Tags: java, reflection

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass {

  private final AnotherClass myField = new AnotherClass() {
       @Override
       public long getSize() { 
            ...
       }
}
```

I have already got the `Class` object of `MyClass`:

```
Class<MyClass> myClazz = LOAD_CLASS("MyClass");
```

how to use **Java reflection** to invoke the `getSize()` method of `myField` defined in `MyClass` ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638826/java-reflection-impact-of-setaccessibletrue , but be cautious.

Comment: @Kevin, I don't see how your link answers my question. My question is not only on how to load the field, but also how to call the getSize() function of the field.

Comment: It describes how to set the accessibility of the field, which will allow you to access a private field via reflection.

Comment: @Kevin, I see that, but my key question is how to invoke the function of private field, your link has no reference on that.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the `Field#setAccessible(boolean b)` method in order to get access on the private field.

You can do :

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
try {
    Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("myField");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    AnotherClass privateField = (AnotherClass) field.get(obj);
    long size = privateField.getSize(); //invoke the getSize() method
    field.setAccessible(false);
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: But I am not able to declare AnotherClass type like your code shows, because I need to load everything at runtime, not compile time

Comment: @KevinBowersox The accessability is only set for that Field instance, and future calls to getDeclaredFields return new instances. So you can just let it go out of scope, and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `getDeclaredMethod` on the `myField` object:

```
Field field = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("myField");
field.setAccessible(true);

Object privateField = field.get(obj);

Method getSizeMethod = privateField.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getSize");

Long result = (Long)getSizeMethod.invoke(privateField);
```