# What is the easiest way to find and run private annotated method?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, private-members

The following example runs `MyClass#myMethod()` only if it is public. It does not run it if it is private.

How to run even if private?

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.reflect.MethodUtils;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.List;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

/**
 * Created by dims on 13.10.2016.
 */
public class CallPrivateMethodTest {

   @Retention(RUNTIME)
   @Target(METHOD)
   public @interface MyAnnotation {
   }

   public static class MyClass {

      @MyAnnotation
      private void myMethod() {
         System.out.println("myMethod() ran");
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      MyClass myObject = new MyClass();

      List<Method> methods = MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation(myObject.getClass(), MyAnnotation.class);


      for(int i=0; i<methods.size(); ++i) {
         try {
            methods.get(i).invoke(myObject);
         } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `setAccessible(true)` on your method.

See [the Javadoc of AccessibleObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-), which in turn is a supertype of Method.

In your example:

```
methods.get(i).setAccessible(true);
methods.get(i).invoke(myObject);
```

---

**EDIT:** As GhostCat pointed out in his answer, not all reflection calls return private methods, too. [It seems that MethodUtils#getMethodsListWithAnnotation](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4/org/apache/commons/lang3/reflect/MethodUtils.java#MethodUtils.getMethodsListWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%2Cjava.lang.Class%29) in fact does not return them.

To solve this problem, you'd have to fetch those methods by yourself:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass ();

Method[] allMethods = myObject.getClass ().getDeclaredMethods ();
List<Method> annotatedMethods = Arrays.stream (allMethods)
                                      .filter (m -> m.getAnnotation (MyAnnotation.class) != null)
                                      .collect (Collectors.toList ());

for (Method method: annotatedMethods) {
  try {
    method.setAccessible (true);
    method.invoke (myObject);
  } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
  } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to run a private method from the class itself. Maybe you should rethink your code ? Otherwise, Alex's answer will do the trick.

More informations on access levels : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

And if you want to use Reflection, you can find even more infos about the behavior here : [Java reflection - impact of setAccessible(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638826/java-reflection-impact-of-setaccessibletrue)

Comment: When using reflection, you can access private fields and methods of classes. But you're right, in most cases one should think about whether it is necessary to call private methods that way.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your comment, I am learning a new things today ! I also added a link on a question about setAccessible behavior

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there can be two reasons why your code doesn't work:

1. That private method shows up in that list; but before calling it, you have to make it **accessible** (you already got an answer for that)
2. Depending on the implementation of that Util class you are using, maybe `getMethodsListWithAnnotation` returns a list that simply doesn't include any *private* methods? ( you see, the mechanism in java reflection to get a hold on *private* methods is different than for *public* methods. thus it wouldnt surprise me if that util class is making the same distinction).

And in any case: *private* methods are *private* for a reason. They represent **internal implementation** details. They are subject to be **changed all the time**.

In that sense: your real problem is that you *think* there is a valid reason to invoke a private method using reflection. You should work on that **first**. If you really think that method should be annotated; and be called via reflection; then at least make it **public**.