# How does Jackson @JsonProperty() work when used to annotate private fields?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

Specifically, I am wondering how, when deserializing an object, the deserializer could set a private field? Thinking of an example class like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty( "My String" );
    private String myString;
}
```

If this is deserialized using `objectMapper.readValue(json, MyClass.class);` how does the resulting object have this field set if it is marked as `private`?

Comment: Related: [What is reflection and why is it useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that it can't normally.  We use lombok to generate the getter/setter for the variables, but you can of course write your own.  Jackson has the same visibility as your main code does, so a private field cannot be mapped without some public getter/setter OR configuring the object mapper like so... `objectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);`.

It wouldn't be able to serialize that either normally.  You can use Lombok `@Getter` and `@Setter` on the class level so Jackson can work with `myString`, or put `@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)` at the class level like below.

```
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
public class MyClass {
    @JsonProperty( "My String" );
    private String myString;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Calling Field.setAccessible(true) before reading or writing a value through reflection does the trick here.

For details see the corresponding javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/AccessibleObject.html#setAccessible-boolean-

But use with care ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Quite a few frameworks allow access to private fields in this manner by using `Field.setAccessible(true)`. It allows the application to ignore the Java language visibility rules (i.e. private) and read or change the value via an instance of the Reflection API `Field` class.

A little more can be found in this question:
[Java reflection - impact of setAccessible(true)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638826/java-reflection-impact-of-setaccessibletrue)